# MailSlot Size Limit?

Tags: windows, api, udp, ipc, mailslot

I want to know is there size limit for total data kept in given MailSlot ?
I found that max message size is 65k so there should be no limit for the total size right ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does exist a limit and as mailslots don't guarantee delivery, extra data will be lost.

Comment: @VisaToHell it would depend on Windows version and other parameters such as consumption of resources. You can do measurements yourself to get precise numbers.

Answer (score 3):

No sure of where your data from. But from Msdn, It says:
The data in a mailslot message can be in any form, but cannot be larger than **424 bytes** when sent between computers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365130(v=vs.85).aspx